# Is there a way to know if Emacs is actuall using a byte ocompiled file (.elc)?

Tags: emacs, byte

Is there a way to know if Emacs is actually using a byte compiled file (.elc)? It is necessary to put all .elc files i a folder or just in the same directory has their original .el?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does it matter?

Comment: I'm guessing he can't see a measurable load time speed-up, and wants to be sure whether the el or elc file is loaded.

Comment: Also there is a long standing "feature" that means Emacs always honours the .elc first which can cause problems if you pull in updates to your .el files from a VCS system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is certainly possible to see if your .emacs is actually a .emacs.elc by examining user-init-file:

```
(if user-init-file
    (if (string-match ".elc" user-init-file)
    (message "Running precompiled .emacs")))
```

I'm not sure about testing arbitrary files being evaluated though.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the messages buffer to see if it's loading up the `.elc` or the `.el` when you do a `require`.

I'd put the byte compiled files in the same directory as the originals because then the requires would work fine and pick up the byte compiled versions without me having to manipulate the load-path.

Comment: Thanks but, how to do a require?

Comment: `(require 'package)` where package is the name of your .el file. The .el file will have a corresponding `provide`.

Answer (score 0):

You could always look up the buffer messages when the emacs starts, also for verbosity, you could start emacs in debug mode.

You can also explicitly specify to require `.elc` files
This is how the require works,

`(require 'foo "/home/user/experimental/foo.el")`

if you have bite compiled files just replace the `.el` to `.elc`, that would load the byte compiled files.